# In TFS can it store SQL Views, Sprocs, functions table scripts as work items?

Tags: team-foundation-server

I'm trying to track changes to sql server2008r2 in Team Foundation Server. As developers create new queries, sprocs, functions etc I would like to be able to track these types of changes to the database in TFS.  Also is it possible to store these scripts as work items?  Or is there a preferred method for keeping track of changes to a database outside of TFS? - Thx Marc

Answer (score 0):

If the developers use Visual Studio database projects (dbproj) then storing the scripts in TFS should be easy enough. I'm not sure what you mean by storing the scripts as work items but when the developer checks in changes, these can be associated with a work item.